# sum of cell value in rows with same value (excel)

Tags: excel

I've made a table where i add all expenses I've made in a certain date. I have made a function that checks all the unique dates that are entered in. Now i want tot add all the expenses that are made at each unique date. so now i'm wondering if there is a way to add the expenses all together for each unique date with some sort of filter. the only thing i could come up with so far is to do something with filters. but that hasn't worked yet. so maybe something along the lines of:

`=UNIQUE(Table2[Day](SUM(TABLE2[Expense]))`

im not sure if this is even the best way to tackle this problem but it has me stumped for a a good while now

Comment: `SUMIFS` should work.

Comment: or just a simple pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNIQUE()` in this way.

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},Table2[Day],SUMIFS(Table2[Expense],Table2[Day],Table2[Day])))
```

With latest release of ***Microsoft-365*** can use-

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(Table2[Day],SUMIFS(Table2[Expense],Table2[Day],Table2[Day])))
```

And for `LAMBDA()` to use with name manager.

```
=LAMBDA(a,b,LET(x,UNIQUE(a),y,SUMIFS(b,a,x),HSTACK(x,y)))
```

[image]